# Using custom for loop inside Laravel Observers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to start counting down when an update event occurs and update other fields based on certain criteria in laravel 5.8 API application.

Basically, these are the steps I want to go through

1. When orders table `orderStatus` field is updated to `processing`, start a 12 minutes count down.
2. During the count down if the orders table `paymentStatus` field gets update from `pending`, stop the count down and update `orderStatus` to `completed`.
3. At the end of count down if orders `paymentStatus` is still pending, update `orderStatus` to `completed` and `paymentStatus` to `aborted`.

To achieve this, I made an OrderObserver that listens for an update event and tried this code

```
public function updated(Order $order)
{
    if ($order->paymentStatus == 'paid') {

        $order->update(['orderStatus' => 'completed']);
    }

    if ($order->paymentStatus == 'processing') {

        // start a timeout function
        for ($orderedAt = $order->created_at; $orderedAt <= $orderedAt->addMinutes(12); $orderedAt->addSecond()) {
            if ($order->paymentStatus !== 'pending') {
                $order->update(['orderStatus' => 'completed']);
                break;
            }

            if ($orderedAt == $orderedAt->addMinutes(12)) {
                $order->update(['orderStatus' => 'completed', 'paymentStatus' => 'aborted']);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Apparently, the first if block works fine but the second does not. After 12 minutes from the created_at time, both `orderStatus` and `paymentStatus` do not get updated.

I feel like the for loop is wrong but I haven't found out the right way to do it yet.

How can I achieve the steps above using the OrderObserver update event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstand what `addMinutes` method does.
`created_at` attribute is a Carbon object, isn't it? If so, `addMinutes` just calculate a sum of time and change the value of the attribute.
And `addSecond` does the same, but with seconds.

If you want to have a long-running script you would have to use a sleep call to stop the process for some seconds.

However, the best solution IMO, you should create a cronb job and check every minute if some order is in `pending` status for 12 minutes, and than change the status.

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling

Comment: Okay sounds like the way to go. So I will compare the order `created_at` time with `created_at + (12 * 60)` and do the updates then keep the first if block in the observer, right?